# How to position a layer underneath a layer that's floated right?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-float

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

I tried the `clearfix` class on the anchor layer, but that didn't change anything.

These questions are remotely similar, but aren't quite close enough to be able to use:

- [Bootstrap button dropdown not below button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35956194)
- [Position an HTML element right under another as opposed to positioned to the right or left](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62964652)

Here's my markup so far:

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="SignIn_Username">Username</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Username is required" id="SignIn_Username" name="SignIn.Username" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" for="SignIn_Password">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Password is required" id="SignIn_Password" name="SignIn.Password" type="password" value="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Remember Me field is required." id="SignIn_RememberMe" name="SignIn.RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="SignIn.RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="SignIn_RememberMe">Remember Me</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row float-right mr-4">
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <Button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm text-nowrap">Sign In</Button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <a href="/">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

What should I do to move the anchor row below the button row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the last row full width with `w-100` class will do the job.

```
<div class="form-group row w-100">
  <div class="col-sm-11">
    <a href="/">Forgot your password?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5vgybzq/)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.